# Booting ubuntu 22.04 from a thumb drive?

Tags: live-usb

I am new to ubuntu. I initially installed ubuntu 20.04 on a dell Inspiron laptop. With 22.04 out, I want to boot it from a thumb drive to see how I like it compared to 20.04. I have created a boot disk with 22.04, but when I start my laptop, It doesn't show up as an option.
I've held <kbd>F12</kbd> on start, I get choice of ubuntu, ubuntu advanced, or Uefi.How do I get the choice of boot options?

Comment: The keys you need to press are machine *firmware* specific.  I have devices that require me to press & hold a key when the machine is off, for it to turn on & offer me to boot external media (ie. *the device firmware has it as a security feature; alas I find it annoying*). The booting is make/model/firmware specific

Comment: You are hitting the Grub menu on your 20.04 installation.   You need to tell the machine to boot on another media, which is earlier than this.  Check your manual.

Comment: I just rembered that on my dell machine, it wasn't holding f12, but tapping it while booting to get a choice!

Comment: Read what the BIOS says (displays on screen) as your system powers up. It'll probably tell you what the magic keys are.

Comment: Dell typically uses f12 for UEFI boot menu. How did you create USB flash drive. Some tools create a BIOS only or UEFI only live installer. Others create one that can be booted in either mode, and you have to choose in the UEFI boot menu whether you want the UEFI:XXX or XXX (which is the BIOS/CSM/Legacy) boot option.

Comment: Try your thumbdrive on a different computer. If it works, you know that the problem isn't the thumbdrive.